# C/C++ bluetooth program to interact with Nrf connect android app

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I am writing a C program to interact with the nrf connect android app on my mobile. I installed libbluetooth-dev on my linux machine for development. The requirement is I need to find the bluetooth USB dongle which is on my Linux machine on the nrf connect app. Then I need to connect from the mobile app to the Linux machine and thenexchange data. To achieve this I wrote the program such that, it first creates a RFComm socket, listens to it and accepts connection if anyone wants to connect and then use Read/write calls to exchange data. The problem is I dont know how to make the USB dongle visible so that it is discoverable on the nrf connect app.

I tried googling around a lot but couldnt find any working suggestions.

Comment: RFComm is not a Bluetooth Low energy protocol. nRFConnect App finds and shows Bluetooth Low energy devices. To find your device in nRF Connect app your USB dongle should be Bluetooth 4.0 and it should advertise. You need to create GATT service on your Linux machine to exchange data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I know RFComm is just one of the transport protocols used on the host. Yes, my USB bluetooth dongle is 4.1. Is advertise same as making discoverable? I dont understand the differernce between these two. So after the create the socket using RFComm, I should just advertise and also start GATT service and then call the "accept" ? Would NRf connect be able to see my USB dongle? If you have any sample source can you please provide me Ravi ?

Answer (score 3):

Bluetooth Low Energy advertisement is different from making device discoverable. Read this [link](https://blog.bluetooth.com/bluetooth-low-energy-it-starts-with-advertising) for a high level explanation of it. Bluez is the name of Linux Bluetooth stack and it exposes DBus API's for all Bluetooth operations. If you want your Linux device to start advertising, you need to use Bluez DBus API. Download Bluez source and see **doc/advertising-api.txt** file to know DBus API for advertisement. For a python example code see **test/example-advertisement**.

Default Linux BLE advertisement interval is 1.2 seconds. So, once you register advertisement with Bluez, using its DBus API, your Linux machine advertises its presence every 1.2 second and nRFConnect Mobile app will find it and shows it in its list.

But advertisement only helps to find the device. To read and write data (read and write is BLE terminology) you need to implement GATT services. Read this [link](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/generic-attributes-overview) to know more, in case you don't know about it. For implementing GATT services in Linux, Bluez has DBus APIs, see **doc/gatt-api.txt**. For python example of how to use these see **test/example-gatt-server** in Bluez source directory.

So, once your nRFConnect Mobile App finds your advertising Linux machine, it shows a Connect Button, if your Linux machine is doing Connectable advertisement. When you click the Connect button, Mobile App performs GATT discovery and retrieves all the GATT services implemented by your Linux Bluetooth application. It then shows up read and write options, using which you can do data transmission.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this solution in couple of days :).